# Crash code when i am using from a method of class?

Tags: java, android

I have a `MainActivity` that connect to a `webService` for `login` that it work good but it get me crash when i am using from a method of `Logins.Class`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText UserName;
    EditText PassWord;
    Button Login;
    String mUserName;
    String mPassWord;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
        PassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPasswprd);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mUserName = UserName.getText().toString().trim();
                mPassWord = PassWord.getText().toString().trim();
                if (mUserName.length() > 0 && mPassWord.length() > 0) {
                    Logins LG = new Logins().UsernameValue(mUserName)
                            .PasswordValue(mPassWord).LOGINS();
            ------> Log.i("OK", LG.getWebresponse());<--- Crash Here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            G.context,
                            G.context.getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.btn_LoginError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And i have a `Logins.Class` for login :

```
public class Logins {
    private String UsernameValues;
    private String PasswordValues;

    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
    String URL = "http://test.com/MobileWebService/Related.asmx";
    private String Webresponse;

    public Logins LOGINS() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            //"xxssxx"
            //123456789
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty("username", UsernameValues);
                request.addProperty("pass", PasswordValues);
                request.addProperty("device", "0");
                request.addProperty("security", 128110);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
                envelope.implicitTypes = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE conn = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                conn.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
                try {
                    conn.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                            .getResponse();
                    Webresponse = response.toString();

                    Log.i("LOG", Webresponse);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("xxx", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        return this;
    }

    public Logins UsernameValue(String value) {
        UsernameValues = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Logins PasswordValue(String value) {
        PasswordValues = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getWebresponse() {
        return Webresponse;
    }

}
```

All of code good work but when i using `getWebresponse Method` i `MainActivity` for get result of `Webresponse` I get crash ?

My crash is :

```
by log Tag :AndroidRuntime
by Log Message :at com.test.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
by PID : 9145
```

Comment: Please add the crash logs.

Comment: what is your error? post your logcat

Comment: "I get crash" is *never* enough information. You need to look in the logs to find the details of the exception, and include them in the question. You may well find that once you read the exception message, it's obvious what's wrong. I'd also *strongly* advise you to start following Java naming conventions.

Comment: What can i do ? mr Dmitry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting directly the `Webresponse` which is still null. it is initialized when the response to web request is done.

now `LG.getWebresponse()` will return null, you need to wait for the web response to be done before you can use the `Webresponse` in your log.

**solution:**

you need to use `asyntask` instead of `thread` and log it in the `onPostExecute()` method that will secure `Webresponse` is initialized to the response of the web request.